# Javascript - Sort months array in chronological order basis current month

Tags: javascript

I have a list of months in javascript. I want to sort it in chronological order based on the current date.

Example
`monthsArr = ["March", "February", "November", "December", "January"]`

if current month is November, sorted array should be `["Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]`

if current month is Jan, sorted array should be `["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Nov", "Dec"]`

Don't worry about conversions to enums or key value pairs. It can be handled. What I am looking for is the logic on how to implement this sort function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this:

```js
var months =
{
  January: 0,
  February: 1,
  March: 2,
  April: 3,
  May: 4,
  // et&c
  November: 10,
  December: 11
};

var monthsArr = ["March", "February", "November", "December", "January"];

var month = new Date().getMonth();

monthsArr.sort(function(m1, m2)
{
  var n1 = months[m1], n2 = months[m2];
  if (n1 < month)
  {
    n1 = n1 + 12;
  }
  if (n2 < month)
  {
    n2 = n2 + 12;
  }
  return n1 - n2;
});

console.log(monthsArr);
```

have a mapping from name and month number like

```
var months =
{
  January: 0,
  February: 1,
  March: 2,
  April: 3,
  May: 4,
  // et&c
  November: 10,
  December: 11
};
```

get the current month

```
var month = new Date().getMonth();
```

sort the array adding 12 to months that are earlier than `month`. that puts them after months that are the same as this month or later.

```
monthsArr.sort(function(m1, m2)
{
  var n1 = months[m1], n2 = months[m2];
  if (n1 < month)
  {
    n1 = n1 + 12;
  }
  if (n2 < month)
  {
    n2 = n2 + 12;
  }
  return n1 - n2;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to get the index of current month,
and then use array slice to recompose the array starting from that index:

```js
var m = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

var cur = new Date().getMonth()

var sorted = [...m.slice(cur), ...m.slice(0,cur)]

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object for the month values and take a wanted month to be the first and sort by a check if the actual month is smaller than the first month or by the month value.

```js
function sort(array, first) {
    var months = { January: 1, February: 2, March: 3, April: 4, May: 5, June: 6, July: 7, August: 8, September: 9, October: 10, November: 11, December: 12 };
    return array.sort((a, b) =>
        (months[a] < months[first]) - (months[b] < months[first]) ||
        months[a] - months[b]
    );
}

console.log(...sort( ["March", "February", "November", "December", "January"], "November"));
console.log(...sort( ["March", "February", "November", "December", "January"], "January"));
```